# this keyword in Fragment is not getting implemented while

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, expandablelistview

I have created two Fragments and the destination Fragment has a an Expandable List View for which there is an Adapter class as well. And when I'm trying to pass this keyword for context which is one of three parameters, it is not working. Can anyone please guide me where I went wrong.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    //Initializations
    expandableListView=view.findViewById(R.id.expand_list);

    content_collection();

    //listadapter
    listAdapter=new ExListAdapter(this, branches,branchntopic);

    expandableListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

Comment: You need to pass context. Declare a `Context context` variable and override `onAttach()`  here you have to intialize like this `this.context = context;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for **getActivity()** or **getContext()** instead of using this.
Since you are using fragment you cannot pass **this** keyword as Context.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is not a valid context in Fragments, you need to use `requireContext()` or `getContext()` instead.

Fragment class does not extends from Context class, so Fragment is not a context. But Activity/AppCompatActivity extends from `Context` class.

Answer (score 0):

Use **getActivity()** in the place of **this**.
That should solve the problem because the list is not in th fragment context but the activity that calls the fragment